# python3 singleton pattern with "with" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I want to write a class with singleton pattern to provide some persistent data storage using pickle/dict:

```
@singleton
class Pdb:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = None
        self.dirty = False
        try:
            with open("data.pck","rb") as fp:
                self.cache = pickle.load(fp)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        except pickle.PickleError:
            pass

        if self.cache is None:
            self.cache = {}

    def flush(self):
        if self.dirty:
            try:
                with open("data.pck","wb") as fp:
                    pickle.dump(self.cache,fp,protocol=4)
            except pickle.PickleError:
                pass
            else:
                self.dirty = False

    def __del__(self): # PROBLEM HERE
        self.flush()
```

When I was using python 2, I can do it by overriding __del__. But it does not appear to be correct in python 3. How can I do it?

If I do it by "with" statement, I will need to pass the instance to each function that I call:

```
def func1(db):
    db.set(...)
    func3(db,x1,x2,...)

with Pdb() as db:
    func1(db)
    func2(db)
```

It is complicated. Is there a pythonic way to do a global scope "with" statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do it by "with" statement, I will need to pass the instance to each function that I call:

No, you don't. Just use your singleton:

```
# global
db = Pdb()

# any other context
with db:
```

All that is required is that the expression *produces* a context manager. Referencing a singleton object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods would satisfy that requirement. You can even ignore the `__enter__` return value, as I did above. The global will still be available to all your functions, the only thing that changes is that `__enter__` and `__exit__` will be called at the appropriate locations.

Note that even in Python 2, you should **not** rely on `__del__` being called. And in the CPython implementation, outside circular references, the rules for when `__del__` are called have not changed between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes. I can do it in this way. But it is same as I call flush() every time I update Pdb(). It costs my CPU time, I want it to flush to the disk automatically when the code is terminated.

Comment: @wonghang: so why not use `with db:` *in your top level function*?